# convert a jpg file to UTF-8 without making it corrupt

Tags: image, jpeg, corrupt

I Have a .jpg file encoded ANSI, I tried converting it to UTF-8 but it made the image corrupt.

NOTE: if you have a solution for any other image format, please post them.

Comment: What did you do exactly to *convert* a jpg file from ANSI to UTF-8? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Opened the .jpg file as text file using Notepad++ and used the function "Convert to UTF-8 Without BOM" and also tried "Convert to UTF-8 With Bom"

Comment: Why would you do that? JPG file isn't encoded as ANSI. JPG is for image, and ANSI is for string.

Comment: OP Question probably meant to say it was in Binary - NOT ANSI

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you base64 encoding, which will enconde files in text for you. Though I am not familiar with the algorithm itself, I can present several websites that do it for you:

- https://www.base64-image.de/
- http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/
- http://www.dailycoding.com/utils/converter/imagetobase64.aspx

Adidtionaly, you can also use such images in your own website by adding them to the HTML. The following answer has some good information regarding this method:

- [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Answer (score -1):

It can be done in NotePad++ easily:

1. Open binary image file into Notepad++
2. Select all text  (ex: Ctrl-A)
3. Go to Plugins->MIMETools->Base64 Encode

Now file shows in Base64 characters instead of binary

Reference:
https://www.technipages.com/how-to-base64-encode-and-decode-in-notepad