# Flutter: Store Image in Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering how to store Images inside Firestore Database instead of the storage and how can I retrieve the Images.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645953/convert-a-jpg-file-to-utf-8-without-making-it-corrupt

Comment: Remember firestore max doc size is around 1MB.

Comment: Hi, Why do you wanna store images in Firestore database? I believe that it is not a good practice to store images in the database, it is not a cost effective way, also the size limit of a document is 1MB in Firestore. Read [storing images in Firestore](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/i4im1y/storing_images_in_firestore/), let me know if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore only stores JSON data. You have to host your image somewhere in order to display it. You should use [firebase_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage) for storing that image.

```
Future<String> getImageUrl() async {
    Reference ref =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('pathToImage');
    String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }
```